# Manage Header and Footer inclusion in php

Tags: php

lets assume that I want to organize my pages as following:

```
<?php include('header.inc.php'); ?>

my-page-content

<?php include('footer.inc.php'); ?>
```

in the header we have `.css` files and in the footer we have `.js` files.

how do I do if I want to load only the CSS and JS that the current page needs?

for example, on the article page I don't need to load the JS resources that manage maps and calendar.

Comment: You could set a variable before your includes that says what js/css should be load and use that in your header and footer. However, it's more common to just have one js/css file that includes it all. The browser caches those files, so they would only be downloaded once anyway.

Comment: Thanks @M.Eriksson, interesting, I didn't think of that idea. So you mean having all the js/css in the header/footer isn't going to reduce the performance of the page since the browser will only load the js/css that the current page needs?

Comment: No, you should put all your JS code into one .js-file and all CSS in one .css file. Then you load that single file on every page. Then the browser will load those files the first time a visitor visits a page, and use the cached version when the user visits other pages after that.

Comment: One css file with all the styles and one js file with all the scripts is not a good solution these days if you keep in mind the loading speed on mobile devices (see Google pagespeed insights: remove unused css and js). The best way is to have one css file with global styles that repeat on every page, and load additional files on pages that actually need additional styling. The situation is similar with js files. The best solution would be that you have declared (in some controller) what css and js should be loaded in specific pages (in addition to the global ones).

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I think it is useless to insert other files into html that will never be used - for cache management purposes. The smaller the html cache space used, the more efficient and powerful the html page will be.

Consider the following example:

> file: **library.php**

```
<?php
   function includeFiles(string $typeFile, array $source_arr, array $request_file): array
   {
     $tmp = [];
     $element = $typeFile === "css" ? "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"%s\">" : "<script src=\"%s\"><script>";
     foreach ($request_file as $file) {
       if (array_key_exists($file, $source_arr)) {
         array_push($tmp, [sprintf($element, "https://example.com" .$css[$file])]);
       }
     }
     return count($tmp) > 0 ? $tmp : false;
   }

  // Make a list of all .js and .css files using the php array:
  $css = [
    // List all the .css files you are using here
    "css1" => "/css/css1.css",
    "css2" => "/css/css2.css",
    "css3" => "/css/css3.css",
    "css4" => "/css/css4.css",
    "css5" => "/css/css5.css"
  ];


  $js = [
    // List all the .js files you are using here
    "js1" => "/js/js1.js",
    "js2" => "/js/js2.js",
    "js3" => "/js/js3.js",
    "js4" => "/js/js4.js"
  ];
?>
```

> file: **main_html.php**

```
<?php   
  include "library.php";

  $css_files = ["css1", "css3", "css5"];
  $headers = implode(PHP_EOL, includeFiles("css", $css, $css_files));

  $js_files = ["js1", "js3", "js5"]; 
  $footer = implode(PHP_EOL, includeFiles("js", $js, $js_files));
  
?>
<!-- Here html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
    
      <?php echo $headers; ?>

      <!-- and other your required head element parameters -->
    </head>
    <body> 
    
    <!-- includes .js files -->

    <?php echo $footer; ?>      

    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: You shouldn't add `include "library.php"` in both the `header.php` and `footer.php` as this will definitely throw errors

Comment: Thanks for the warning, I didn't realize that. Thank you for your attention. I updated the answer, actually the php snippet itself. The "footer.php" file is not needed. @DarkBee